# Using powershell to restart computers if -LastBootupTime = -gt 10 days

Tags: database, windows, powershell, networking

I'm trying to make a script that checks how long the computers on a network are on, and if they are on for more then 10 days they need to restart. I'm planning to run the script automatically with task manager every Sunday.

Thanks to @vonPryz I've got something like this now:

```
$clients = get-content "C:\Documents\lijstcomputers.txt"

foreach ($client in $clients) {

    if (test-connection -computername $client -BufferSize 16 -Count 1 -Quiet) {
        write-Host $client is online


        $uptime = (get-date) - (gcim Win32_OperatingSystem -computer $client).LastBootUpTime

        $startTime = [Management.ManagementDateTimeConverter]::ToDateTime((gwmi  Win32_OperatingSystem -computer $client).lastbootuptime)


        if( $uptime.days -ge 10) {
            restart-computer -computername $client
            add-content -path "c:\path\to\log.txt" -value "$client, $startTime, $uptime"
        }
    }
    else {
    write-Host $client is offline
    }
}
```

But now I'm getting this error:

```
    gcim : WinRM cannot complete the operation. Verify that the specified computer name is valid, that the computer is accessible over the network, and
 that a firewall exception for the WinRM service is enabled and allows access from this computer. By default, the WinRM firewall exception for publ
ic profiles limits access to remote computers within the same local subnet.
At line:1 char:25
+ $uptime = (get-date) - (gcim Win32_OperatingSystem -computer $client).LastBootUp ...
+                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ConnectionError: (root\cimv2:Win32_OperatingSystem:String) [Get-CimInstance], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80338126,Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimCmdlets.GetCimInstanceCommand
    + PSComputerName        : ASND0042

Cannot find an overload for "op_Subtraction" and the argument count: "2".
At line:1 char:1
+ $uptime = (get-date) - (gcim Win32_OperatingSystem -computer $client).LastBootUp ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest
```

Comment: So what's the question? How to boot a computer? How to write the results in a file? Something else?

Comment: You may want to look into importing/exporting to CSV (use `Get-Help *csv*`), or you want to correct an error in your code (which you could specify), but you haven't done either. If you're looking to export to CSV, then that is not a stack overflow question either, since a quick google search will provide you with all the answers you need.

Comment: @vonPryz I just can't find a way to do all of that in one script since I just started using powershell. The question is if you can help me make a script that will restart a computer that has been on for more than 10 days, and give me a nice, easy to read overview on what has happened. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @MaximeFranchot I've tried many things but I can't seem to find the correct commands. The CSV thingy is just a plus.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already got some parts covered, this isn't just a plz give me teh codez and thus warrants help. So let's outline how the whole script should look.

```
# Write computer names into a file, one per row for easier management
$clients = get-content "c:\ListOfComputers.txt"

foreach ($client in $clients) {
# If computer's not up, there's no need to check uptime
    if (test-connection -computername $client -BufferSize 16 -Count 1 -Quiet) {
        write-Host $client is online

        # Get uptime
        $uptime = (get-date) - (gcim Win32_OperatingSystem -computer $client).LastBootUpTime
        # Get start time
        $startTime = [Management.ManagementDateTimeConverter]::ToDateTime((gwmi  Win32_OperatingSystem -computer $client).lastbootuptime)

        # Restart the client if uptime's at least 10 days.
        if( $uptime.days -ge 10) {
            restart-computer -computername $client
        # Add client name, start date and uptime into a log file
            add-content -path "c:\path\to\log.txt" -value "$client, $startTime, $uptime"
        }
    }
    else {
    write-Host $client is offline
    }
}
```

This skeleton can be further improved by adding some error handling and, say, proper CSV export.

Comment: It seemed this would work just fine but I'm getting this error after changing it. (see article)